# Off-topic description is outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I flag a question off-topic, the description under "off-topic" leads

"Questions on Application Security are expected to generally relate to Q&A site for application security professionals...."

This description needs to be updated to the more general content of the site (I.T. Security) rather than what the original area51 proposal was (AppSec)

Comment: Yup, you're right - but I'm not even sure where to change that. I *thought* it was from the FAW, but now thats changed and its still here, so I'm wrong... Let me check this out.

Comment: @Avid - FAW :-) I'll have a hunt round as well.

Comment: It seems that we cannot change it directly - only the SO team themselves. I put a query out to @RobertCartaino, will work with him on that...

Comment: In the meantime, we should have the text worked out ahead of time, since its not as wikiable as the FAQ. Any offers?

Comment: I would suggest that we take a cue from the FAQ's description of what kind of questions should be asked here--The only problem is that it seems that the FAQ should be updated as well, as it is pretty AppSec centric----"IT Security Stack Exchange is for IT security professionals to discuss vulnerabilities like XSS, buffer overflows, SQL injection, CSRF, clickjacking. Discussions related to OWASP projects, tools, papers, and other materials are encouraged."

Comment: @Josh - updated the FAW yesterday. hopefully it is a bit better, but all comments from users help

Comment: @Rory - Looks good to me for now. Probably want to edit a little more before the site is launched.  For instance, the OWASP portion feels out of place now....

Comment: Do we need to rollback the status-completed tag, since this is not actually completed?

Answer (score 4):

OK, I changed it to

> Questions on $SiteName are expected to relate to professional IT security concerns within the scope defined in the [faq](/faq).

all good?

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff - yes I think thats a good solution (at least for now, till the scope gets shaken out a bit more and the FAW updated...) Can I suggest that you put that as the default on new sites? I'm sure they'll have the same issue at some point... (yknow, unless that's editable in wiki also...)

Comment: Heh, @Jeff - I assumed the $SiteName was a placeholder that would get replaced at runtime by "IT Security - Stack Exchange"... See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/fake-ap-software-with-wpa2-support, the "$SiteName" appears a literal...